# Titanium How do i call functions from an array of function names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, titanium, titanium-alloy

Hello I'm working with Titanium Alloy and I have a problem with call some function from other files:
I have this file in /lib:
validation.js

```
exports.isInt=function(obj){
if(parseInt(obj.value) != parseFloat(obj.value)) {
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
```

};

and in my controller i call it:
controller1.js

```
var split = data.pregunta.attributes.pr_validacion.split(','); //{'function1','function2'}
var valida = require('validation');
for (var p in split) {
    alert(split[p]); //show: 'function1'
    if(! valida.split[p]()){
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it shows me a message that split[0] is not a valid object, how I cando to make me take the name of the function?

Thanks U!

Answer (score 0):

You should use valida[split[p]] in your controller1.js:

```
var split = data.pregunta.attributes.pr_validacion.split(','); //{'function1','function2'}
var valida = require('validation');
for (var p in split) {
    alert(split[p]); //show: 'function1'
    if(! valida[split[p]]()){
        return false;
    }
}
```